# States and Countries select box - best way to do it?

Tags: php, jquery, select, combobox, countries

this may seem trivial but I'm setting up, on a profile form page I'm building, a countries and states select box such that when you select the US or Canada then the states box would display states of the selected countries else it would display a None Applicable instead. My countries and states are in a database and I'm populating m y selects from that - I would like a simple yet proper way to do this - I noticed that for some reason disabling select options is not supported in all browsers :( - or is there any nice free snippet online I could use [maybe I'm feeling too lazy to code this here]

I'm using JQuery for the javascripting here though.

---

Edited

Thanks for the replies - the cascading drop down seems to do what I need but I'm looking for a php based solution.

How have mainstream websites accomplished this btw. Because I don't want to leave it to the user and end with entries including American/ Canadian states with countries that are not the US/Canada.

---

The Ajax idea is what I had in mind but the thing is that the application form I'm building has a section where you can add contact addresses. Its been built such that you can add multiple addresses to the same contact. Theres an add button which just duplicates the address inputs using a javascript function so basically when you submit the form you have data like :

_POST['address[]'], _POST['city[]'], _POST['state[]'],_POST['country[]']

The thing is binding this action to each instance of state and countries when created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would not even show the state selector, if neither US nor Canada has been selected from the country selector. This approach has two advantages, users from all other countries are not bothered by meaningless content, you don't have to deal with unwanted input.

Now I would save the value of the country selector via AJAX and then send/activate the additional selector div with the response, if needed.

After your edit: How flexible are you then? If you are stuck with some existing code then a cron job which eliminates unnecessary state entries might be another way.

I mean you could also handle the state later on retrieval but I assume there is also preexisting code which creates addresses and that code doesn't check if the state makes sense...

Comment: Taken your advice and made a simple javascript function which on page load on an AJAX call retrieves a json array of states stored in a global var and then I populate the states combo box based upon the selection in the countries select box. Working like a charm, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Don't forget to use autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Attach an onchanged handler to the c]Country dropdown. In the handler, use Ajax to retrieve a State/Province list for the selected country, the populate the State/Province dropdown with that list and enable the State/province dropdown.

In the static HTML, disable the State/Province dropdown.

Comment: This is a great idea however how do I fill up the select combos on a similar form if I wish to edit an already existing entry?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

See if the [CascadingDropdown](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) Extender can do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in ASP.NET is to use a cached Usercontrol for the Countries dropdownlist. This dropdownlist has a RequiredFieldValidator attached to it with initial value set to "Select one". The States dropdownlist could be included in the same usercontrol and could be populated based on an AJAX request based on selection of the Countries dropdownlist. (as @tpdi mentions in his answer)